# Javascript Função Onclick Em conflito com o form?

Tags: javascript, html

Possuo um formulário que envia dados para outra página, gostaria de resetar alguns inputs após o envio do formulário logo tentei isso:

```
<form name='protocolo' id='protocolo' class='excluirclienteform' action='makeprotocolo.php'  target="_blank" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <br>
                    <label>Selecione uma empresa</label><br>
                    <select name='id' class="selects2"  required>
                        <option value="">selecione a empresa</option>
                            <?php
                            $buscarid=$pdo->prepare("SELECT ID,nome FROM usuario WHERE permissao = 1 ORDER BY ID ASC");
                            $buscarid->execute();
                            while($linha=$buscarid->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                                echo "<option  value=".$linha["ID"].">".$linha["ID"]." ".$linha["nome"]."</option>";
                            }
                            ?>
                        </option>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <label>Selecione um item</label>
                    <br>
                    <select name='item' class="selects2"  required>
                        <option value="">selecione a empresa</option>
                            <?php
                            $buscarid=$pdo->prepare("SELECT id,nome FROM protocolo_item order by nome asc");
                            $buscarid->execute();
                            while($linha=$buscarid->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                                echo "<option  value=".$linha["id"].">".$linha["id"]." ".$linha["nome"]."</option>";
                            }
                            ?>
                        </option>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <label>Quantidade</label>
                    <br>
                    <input type='number' step="1" name='quantidade' id='quantidade' size='20' maxlength="10">
                    <br>
                    <label>Descrição</label>
                    <br>
                    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="descricao" id='descricao' maxlength="500"></textarea>
                    <br><br>
                    <button type='submit' id='inseriritem' name='enviar' onsubmit="document.getElementById('#descricao').reset();">Inserir</button>
                    <br><br>
                </form>
```

Porém não obtive sucesso, tentei resetar o input várias formas, colocando em uma função js (o que seria o certo no caso), tentei usar jquery entre outros porém não obtive sucesso, logo acredito que possa haver algum conflito dentro do meu formulário que possa estar causando esse problema da função não gerar o resultado esperado (que no caso é resetar o text area descricao).

Comment: Target _blank, a outra página é apenas um código php para inserir os dados, ela retorna uma mensagem e fecha automaticamente, essa página continua aberta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `onsubmit` está no lugar errado. Você deve colocá-lo na tag `<form>`. Outro problema é que o `reset()` só é aplicável ao objeto `<form>`, e não a um elemento individual de formulário.

Como você não pode limpar o campo no submit (senão ele será enviado vazio), chame uma função após um pequeno *delay* usando `setTimeout` no `onsubmit`:

```
<form onsubmit="setTimeout(limpa, 100)"...
                  ^^^^^^^
```

E coloque a função `limpa()` no JavaScript limpando o campo com `value = ''`:

```
<script>
function limpa(){
   document.getElementById('descricao').value = '';
}
</script>
```

Ou poderia também fazer tudo no `onsubmit` sem chamar função:

```
<form onsubmit="setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById('descricao').value = '' }, 100)"...
```

Comment: Cara, tentei isso de várias maneiras e nenhuma funcionou, inclusive tentando dentro do form, porém por alguma bruxaria a sua deu certo (já havia tentado o delay no form submit e não tinha conseguido sucesso), muito obrigado pela ajuda!